# Node.js: Error handling when using pipe with streams

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I am reading large CSV and transforming it to create multiple other csv's. Here is my relevant part of the code. How do i error handle each step in this case?

I have added a generic `on('error')` but that does not seem to get triggered always.

Does each chain in the below code need its own `on('error')`? or is there a more elegant way to do this.

```
    await fs.createReadStream(m.path)
      .pipe(csv.parse({delimiter: '\t', columns: true}))
      .pipe(csv.transform((input) => {
        //delete input['Date'];
        console.log(input);
        return input;
      }))
      .pipe(csv.stringify({header: true}))
      .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(transformedPath))
      .on('finish', () => {
        console.log('finish....');
      }).on('error', () => {
        console.log('error.....');
      });
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `stream` API require each "middleware" to have its own `.on("error")` handler.

However, NodeJS ships with a pipeline utility function for this use case ([stream.pipeline](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_stream_pipeline_source_transforms_destination_callback)). The pipeline handles errors and closes streams correctly.

Using a pipeline, the example code provided by the OP would be written as:

```js
import stream from "stream";
import util from "util";

try {
  await util
    .promisify(stream.pipeline)(
      fs.createReadStream(m.path),
      csv.parse({delimiter: '\t', columns: true})
      csv.transform((input) => {
        //delete input['Date'];
        console.log(input);
        return input;
      }),
      csv.stringify({header: true}),
      fs.createWriteStream(transformedPath)
    );

  console.log('finish....');
}
catch( error ){
  console.log('error.....');
}
```